# Need help resolving error in SOLR 3.3 related to dataimport handler with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, solr

I am trying install dataimport handler in solr 3.3 for connecting mysql db to send data to solr for indexing. However I am getting the following error.

HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: false in solr.xml ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler' at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:423) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:459) at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:157) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:563) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254) and so on..

I have placed following in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">store-name-data-config.xml</str>
</lst> 
</requestHandler>
```

sample of store-name-data-config.xml is

```
- <dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" user="myusername" password="mypassword" /> 
- <document name="db name">
<entity name="store name" query="select name, address, city, state, zip, phone, web_address, area, area_group from store" /> 
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

I have placed the necessary files from contrib/dataimporthandler/libs directory to WEB-INF directory, although I think this where the problem might be, but not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the dataimport jars are located in the directories configured in [solrconfig.xml with the `<lib>` directives](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#lib).